# Cordova plugin is not installed on local device?

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm just about at my wits end with the Cordova Facebook plugin. You can't test this with ionic serve as the Cordova plugins don't load. You can't test this with ionic cordova run browser as it no longer supports unsecure connections. Now when testing on an actual mobile phone it states: cordova-plugin-facebook-connect not installed.

Correct me if I'm wrong but are Cordova plugins not already pre-installed on actual mobile devices and the plugins are only temporarily downloaded to emulate them on PC? Aside from this, the plugin was already included in the project files, but when trying to re-add the plugin it states "Plugin "cordova-plugin-facebook-connect" already installed on browser.".

Does anyone know why this occurs on the local device? Do i need to run something other than '.\gradlew bundle' in the 'Platforms\Android' folder or 'ionic cordova build android' in the root directory? I'm officially out of ideas.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No plugins are not pre-installed. You must install them yourself. Please review the installation instructions found here https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect#installation